# Netsuite Custom Sublist

Tags: sql, netsuite, sublist

I have created a **custom Item sublist** in Netsuite, it shows all the information I need except for the ITEM DESCRIPTIONS. I can use `{item.description}` to show the *default* sales description, but I need to show the descriptions as shown on the RECORD.

Comment: Which field from the record are you trying to display? Where are you trying to display it? A search? A PDF?

Comment: I am trying to display the Item DESCRIPTIONS from transactions (Sales Orders, Invoices, Purchase Orders, etc.) and I am trying to display this data on; Item > Related Records > Transactions *this sublist*)

Answer (score 0):

The description line field in transaction records is called Memo, so `{item.memo}` should work.

Comment: Hi Michoel {item.memo} isn't working for me. See new comment I left above.